# How to fix Django in virtualenv on FreeBSD Raspberry reloads constantly

Tags: django, python-3.x, raspberry-pi, freebsd

I have installed a fresh FreeBSD installation on a Raspberry PI 3+ with Python3.6 and virtualenv.

Inside virtualenv 'web' I have created the Django Project 'prod' and uWSGI.

I can start a uWSGI server instance without problem.
But if I try to run

```
python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000
```

Django reloads the server constantly because it detects changes to python files:

```
December 07, 2018 - 15:00:59
Django version 2.2, using settings 'prod.settings'
Starting development server at http://0.0.0.0:8000/
Quit the server with CONTROL-C.
/usr/local/lib/python3.6/gettext.py changed, reloading.
Watching for file changes with StatReloader
Performing system checks...

System check identified no issues (0 silenced).

December 07, 2018 - 15:01:05
Django version 2.2, using settings 'prod.settings'
Starting development server at http://0.0.0.0:8000/
Quit the server with CONTROL-C.
/usr/local/lib/python3.6/uuid.py changed, reloading.
Watching for file changes with StatReloader
Performing system checks...

System check identified no issues (0 silenced).
```

this happens for every file in '/usr/local/lib/python3.6/'

I have the same setup on a VirtualBox (not 100% same, the VirtualBox is a amd64 version of FreeBSD)

if I run:

```
python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000 --noreload
```

the Server is reachable and stable

I reformated the SD card and started the Project anew, same result.

The only change to a file I did:

```
ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['X.X.X.X']
```

where X.X.X.X is the Outside IP

Comment: But why don't you use uwsgi? The development server is for development.

Comment: Thanks for the fast reply
I do use uWSGI. But it dowsn't work there too, as Django reloads constantly, uWSGI cant serve

Comment: Then I don't understand your question. If you use uwsgi, you don't need runserver.

Comment: sorry i wasn't finished with my reply before sending it...:

 I do use uWSGI. But it dowsn't work there too, as Django reloads constantly, uWSGI cant serve

Comment: @daniel-roseman you were right, I made a wrong assumption... If I run uWSGI it serves the Django Debug site.
But couldn't this cover a problem with Django?

Answer (score 0):

Same issue here. Downgrading from Django 2.2 to Django 2.1.7 fixed it for me.